# C# Logic to delay an action

Tags: c#, wait, dispose

I have a Dispose method on a C# class A that is meant to clean up. When the user of this class calls a.Dispose() I want to wait a few seconds (say 5 seconds) to let some background work finish, and only then (i.e. when 5 seconds times out) execute the code of Dispose (regardless whether the background work finished or not). The client doesn't know about this background work, only this class A knows. Is there an elegant way to code this?

Comment: Is the background work asynchronous? [IAsyncDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-disposeasync) might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution to your problem could be to use [IAsyncDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-disposeasync).

```
public class Work : IAsyncDisposable
{
    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync( )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "Disposing async" );

        // This delay is a simulation of your closing logic.
        await Task.Delay( TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 5 ) ).ConfigureAwait( false );

        Console.WriteLine( "Disposing async complete" );
    }
}

public class Program
{
    static async Task Main( string[ ] _ )
    {
        // You can use it with an implicitly scoped using
        // statement.
        await using var work1 = new Work( );

        // Or you can explicitly define the scope.
        await using ( var work2 = new Work2( ) )
        {
        }

        // Or you can instantiate your class and then wrap it
        // in a using statement.            
        var work3 = new Work( );
        await using ( work3 )
        { 
        }

        // Or you can call DisposeAsync explicitly.
        var work4 = new Work( );
        await work4.DisposeAsync( );
    }
}
```

This is just a toy example to show you how you could use `IAsyncDisposable`. Try running it and observe the console output.

Since you gave no details about what your real application is doing this is the best I can do.

I should also note, that `classes` that implement `IAsyncDisposable` will typically also implement `IDisposable`. The link I provided will give you further details about this.

Answer (score -1):

The contract for "dispose" is essentially "related resources are released before the method return". Since `Dispose` is synchronous method it means you can't delay releasing the resource past the return from the method removing any timer/async based solutions. So this leaves only one (and hence "an elegant") way of doing what you want  - `Thread.Sleep(5000)`.

Note: there is likely some different design that avoids such synchronous delay. Such synchronous delays will freeze UI for example in client application when run on main thread or cause significant problems with timeouts in server side code.

Comment: Whoever downgraded this answer please give your reasoning.